# How can I get the last character in every line after splitting a text?

Tags: linux, string

Input:

```
sed "s/ //g" flag29 | tr -d "\n" | tr "," "\n"
```

Output:

Loremipsumdolorsitamet
melperfectovolutpatassueveritno
ususonetphaedrumvulputateet.Periculisevertiturconstitutonoeam
vimeidelectusoportere.Sedquidamadmodumrecusabout
vimsteteleifendlaboramusex.Iudicoaliquidquian
adquopossitmolestiae.Iderosmunerevix.Necsolumtritanieu
odiopersequerissitin.Cumeurebumdicantpopulo
eueamnibhnostroliberavisse
adpostealuptatumpartiendoest.Adestrebumsaperettheophrastus
duisviditponderumutest
melnonumyprobatusea.Eumnononumespraesent.Eamutiustosoleat
vocentassueveritusuid.Librisaudiamreprimiqueeuvix
etullumiustoexplicarivim
nametzrilnostro.Populoquodsiatpri.Utamuraliquipvisei
hisdoloremaiestatisex.Viditcotidiequeseate.Noeostantasfacilispertinacia
estidrebumpericulaconsulatu.Quianmutatoporterequalisque
cumeipopulomuciusurbanitas.Tollitminimumeasea
dictapartemverearaneum.Necatquioptionpertinaxat
causaeaccommodareidvim.Admagnaerantmandamusqui.Eamodusmalorumoporteatvix
mazimdolorumappareatprono
adaliquamatomorumsea.Viditsimuldolorumvixea
atmeispossittractatosquo
neusuerosverovocent.Noiusgraecoomittamindoctum.Hisneposteaaliquid
hisvivendumnecessitatibusan.Pereiaffertadmodumdissentiet
namaliquidmentitummaiestatisea
uttacimatesdissentiasquo.Addiscereveritusintellegamius.Utmelnovummundiprincipes
nectalenostrolabiturut.Temeimodusluciliuslegendos.Etseaexercilatinesalutandi
etiusaeternointellegatsuscipiantur
euperenimfierentscriptorem.Adinanidictasblanditmel
idnatumhendreritreferrentursed.Ceteromaluissetiusei
visnonovumtritanivoluptua.Namquotassueveritid
persiusconceptamnecne.Estofficiisvoluptatibusan
seaeamunereomnesqueposidonium.Inaperiritibiqueapeirianvim
veleudecorepartiendo
verorepudiaretemei.Hastotaadipiscingat
velquotfacernusquamid
velilludaliquamex.Euullumpartiendoqualisquesea
usuethincmodussigniferumque
epicuripercipiturhonestatiseisit.Erantpercipitestat
nullaapeirianvelat.Unumlaudemvoluptatumquiad
duisautemidsed
atvelexplicariefficiantur.Eiatquiscribentureum
salutandimnesarchumdisputandousuan
nevixnumquamdoloremperfecto.Eiseasumocontentiones
necomnesoffenditconseteturut.Cumutplaceratpraesentpatrioque
neduoalterumphaedrumadipisci.Adipisciadversariumeumei
eameasuscipitpericulareprimique.Cuiudicoquaestiovis.Audiamrecusaboeupro
scriptacommunemeaan.Pereanibhomnesque
nejustolibriscommunequi
atiusilludposseefficiantur.Sintnobisquaerendumatpri
eaaliitollitscripseritquo
eisalequaerendumvoluptatibushis.Illudurbanitasduocu
quisdicereteuvis.Usuurbanitasconceptamdisputationiat.Nihillatineconsequatexmel
vocentblanditurbanitasvimin.Adeamexerciconcludaturque
neneczrilsapientemcontentiones.Hasidputantdictasquodsi.Vissimuldictasconvenireex
priesseexpetendahendreritne.Visessevivendono
neerremlegimusvolutpateos.Etvocibussensibussuavitatemea
brutelegimusestcu.Tehisetiamtritanialiquid
tehisnobisquaestio.Inpereripuitpersecutirationibus
dicoconstituamsitid.Sitmovetquandoeligendiut
ignotainterpretariseosat.Inenimiisqueinermisvel
eimelpersiusprompta.Neseasanctusdelicatissimi
meinecaseferrivulputate
atmelpericulisocurreret.Dicoverearaccusamusuex

I want to get the last character in every string, I tried piping `grep "$.*"`

so it would look something like this:

```
sed "s/ //g" flag29 | tr -d "\n" | tr "," "\n" | grep "$.*"
```

but i get no output.

Comment: do you mean last character on every line?

Comment: yes, sorry i will make that edit to make it more clear

Comment: let me know if the info below works OK or needs any revision

Comment: Thanks this did exactly what I needed, if you want could you explain how you used sed to make it so that it grabs the last character of each line even though every line had varying fields?

Comment: The `.*` below did most of the work. Many regex match in a maximum fashion; for better details try a web search with these keywords: `regex` `greedy`

Comment: Thanks I found this really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last `sed`: match zero or more of anything with `.*` followed by any single character `.` placed within a `\(sub-expression\)` and anchor the pattern with `$`; substitute everything with the sub-expr match referenced by `\1`

```
sed "s/ //g" flag29 | tr -d "\n" | tr "," "\n" | sed 's/.*\(.\)$/\1/'
```